# React Props not working, complete beginner

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm following tutorial carefully, but I just can't pass props to function component and extract data from props object.
I think it's export-import error, but I would really appreciate nudge in the right direction.
I'm using create-react-app

---

*App.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const Greeting = (props) => <h1>Hello {props.name}</h1>;

export default Greeting;
```

*It only prints out Hello in H1 tag, and just leaves out the rest of it.*

---

*index.js*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const element = <Greeting name="irakli" />;

ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

---

Comment: Instead of Greeting you should change to App because you are importing it as App. So const element = <App name="John" />

Comment: Change `import App from './App';` to `import Greeting from './App';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Greeting you should change to App because you are importing it as App. So

```
const element = <App name="John" />
```

Comment: Tried it, still doesn't work :( appreciate the response though <3

Comment: It displays nothing instead of displaying name. Here's the screen :http://prntscr.com/lhdkpy

Comment: can you check the terminal any error or warnings are there ?

Answer (score 1):

In My index.js:

Instead of `import App from './App';` replace with `import Greeting from './App';`

Comment: I think i tried that too before, and certainly tried it now. still nothing displays. :( thanks though

Answer (score 0):

in App.js use 'export default App'.

Comment: What does this cover that existing answers didn't address? When answering older questions with existing answers it is very important to point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses. Also answers should include explanation of how and why they work.